# Android - Using CPU Cores more effectively

Tags: android, multithreading

Android: OS 4.1.2

The system I am running has 4 CPU cores and I am running a multithreaded application. Sometimes the number of active threads increase to 3 or 4. But I see that CPU uses only one or two cores. It holds the threads from running. I captured TraceView and it shows that 2 threads ideally can run concurrently on 2 CPU cores. But only one CPU core is initially allocated. The execution alternates between these two threads for some time. Finally, at after about 200-300ms 2 cores are allocated for these two threads.

Note that CPU governer is set to "Interactive".

Am I missing some configuration, some setting, some programming error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing some configuration, some setting, some programming error?

No. The decisions for how many cores to power on, and what those cores do, is up to the OS and device manufacturer, not us as app developers.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

There are tradeoffs that chipset manufacturers make with regards to power consumption, core usage, and core frequency. The driver will down clock or turn off a core to save power. If you aren't doing anything very CPU intensive that would cause both cores to need to be on and at max frequency, it is quite likely that executing both threads on one core is the correct choice. CommonsWare is correct in that these are decisions that the chipset manufacturers are in the best position to make.

If you are curious and have a rooted device, you can verify the current clock speed for each of your cores like so:

```
adb shell cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
adb shell cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

(Disclaimer: just for testing purposes) You can also force your core to max frequency like so:

```
adb shell "echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
```

The interactive governor is what causes the CPU frequency to change based on demand.

Of course if you force your CPU freq to maximum you'll burn through your battery in no time.